# Html different photo sizes in a table

Tags: html

Hello I have a problem I want to put some random photos in different sizes  in an Html table than I have created but when I put the photos Inside the table the size of the table breaks I tried many things but nothing changed here is my table `

```html
<! doctype html>
<html>
<head
</head>

<body>

<table border="1" width="40%">

    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:red; padding-bottom:50px;"><br /><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td>
        <td style="background-color:green; padding-right:60px; padding-bottom:10px;"><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td>
        <td style="background-color:black; padding-right:80px; padding-bottom:20px;" rowspan="2"><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:white; padding-bottom:25px;" rowspan="2">cell</td>
        <td style="background-color:orange; padding-bottom:50px;"><br /><br /><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:purple; padding:110px; padding-bottom:120;" rowspan="2">
            <table border="1" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td><td><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td><td><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:gray; padding-bottom:150px" rowspan="2"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:pink; padding:40px; padding-bottom:50px;" rowspan="2">cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color:yellow; padding:50px; padding-bottom:30px;" colspan="2">cell</td>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

source: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

You need to insert your image between your `<td></td>`

```
 <table border="1" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td><p><font color="white">cell</font>
                    </p></td><td><p><font color="white">cell</font>
                    **<img src="img_girl.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" style="width:500px;height:600px;">
                    </p></td>**
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td><td><p><font color="white">cell</font></p></td>
                </tr>
            </table>*emphasized text*
```